# determine dimension of matrix under some conditions

Tags: matlab, matrix

suppose that we have matrix  with size mXn, and i want to return matrix  which contains elements of original matrix at odd indices,i wrote function which is called  odd_index, for instance here is code

```
function B=odd_index(M);
% M- is given matrix
% purpose of this code is to return elements at odd indices 
[m,n]=size(M);% calculate dimensions  of matrix
B=[];%initialize matrices
% let run loops
i=1;
for k=1:m
    for l=1:n 
    if (mod(k,2)==1 && mod(l,2)==1)
              B(k,i)=M(k,l);
            i=i+1;    
    end
   end
end
B=B(B>0);
B=reshape(B,2,2);
end
```

for instance

```
(1,1,),(1,3),(3,1),(1,5),(5,1),(3,5),(5,3),(3,3),(5,5),(1,7)
```

and so on, what will be  dimension of such matrix? i think it will be (m-2)X(n-4) but i am not sure about this  and please could you help me?

Comment: `reshape(M(1:2:end,1:2:end).',[],1)`?

Comment: it does not have matrix form

Comment: For matrix form use `M(1:2:end,1:2:end)`. Your final step of reshaping into `2x2` might not be true for a generic case. That step looks ambiguous to me.

Answer (score 0):

solution will be  by help of @ Divakar

M(1:2:end,1:2:end)